# PHP/ Get current URL + conditional

Tags: php

I am not very good at php but I want to detect if a user is in the home of the website such as;

```
<?php
if (current path = http://website.com/ || website.com)
{?>

<div>We are in home</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div>do something</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Someone help me please thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $pageName = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

 if($pageName == 'http://website.com'){
       echo '<div>We are in home</div>';
 } else { do something };
```

Comment: That almost worked, but if the current path is `http://website.com/?sortby=highest` it will detect the index.php still, I echoed the value in the pagename variable and is "index" i would need the url instead so that i can detect if a user is in `http://website.com` or `http://website.com/?sortby=highest`